# Does the repetition (Chazaras Hashatz) need to be recited in the same place as the silent prayer (Amidah/shemonah esre)?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, chazzan-prayer-leader, tefillah-betzibbur

Does the repetition (Chazaras Hashatz) need to be recited in the same place as the silent prayer (Amidah/shemonah esre)?

To be specific can a minyan that already prayed silently together move somewhere else for the repetition?

Does the distance make a difference to whether the minyan is permitted to move.

Comment: The SA 69:1 says that if 10 people davened themselves and then got together for chazzaras hashatz then it is permitted. Obviously they didn’t daven in the same place because in that case they would’ve been a minyan (it sounds like it was at the same time). So based on that, it would seem that changing places is not a problem. The MB paskens differently, but for a different reason.